# Failed to initialize Jenkins io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: 'assignments' is deprecated while deploying a new version of my jenkins

Tags: jenkins

This is the problem, I faced, this issue is being claunched recently in jenkins last month.
I will provide solution for that here after my resolution.

I resolved it alreday now.

eldfoasdyadydosiyisdhyfdihsdfisfdhhoisdfywae80oywfeywfe9pwefya9peyfaf

Answer (score 0):

```
items:
    - assignments:  --remove this
      - "AWS-Role 12345 Developer"  --remove this
    - entries:  --add this
      - group: "AWS-Role 12345 Developer" --add this
      name: "RestrictProdAccess"
      pattern: "^(?!.*PROD).*"
      permissions:
      - "Job/Cancel"
      - "Job/Build"
```

Comment: TIP: Assignments can be groups or users. The `entries` subkey needs to match (`group` or `user`).